# Writing an int[] to disk quickly?

Tags: java, android, mobile

In my Android app, I have a Bitmap object and an int[]. One algorithm in my app copies the Bitmap pixel values to the int[] and then modifies the values in the latter.

*I want to save the contents of the raw int[] to disk as quickly as possible. What is a fast and memory efficient way to do this? (i.e. calling a .writeInt function on each int[] item would be a very slow way to do this in Android as there is no JIT on most devices)*

I found that if I create a byte[] of the same size as the int[] and copy the int[] to the byte[], I can then use one of many file io methods to write the byte[] to disk in one API call. However, this uses a lot of extra memory as I now have two versions of the int[].

Failing this, perhaps there is some method that will directly write the int values of a Bitmap into a file? If so, I could copy the int[] back into the Bitmap object and use this.

By the way, I don't want to use ".png" compression and just want to save the raw values as the latter is much quicker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will have to allocate a buffer (`byte[]`), of a size that maximizes performance and still uses only a reasonable amount of memory. Maybe something like 8K.

You then loop over your array in pages ( buffer size / 4 ), fill the buffer and write it out. The next page can then reuse the same buffer. Make sure you correctly handle the last page, which may be half empty (of course with a bitmap, it probably aligns to 8K buffers anyway).

Comment: You could also give ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(myIntArray) a try. Maybe it does something clever natively under the hood.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a go. I'm quite surprised about the lack of writeIntArray functions though. By the way, is there a simple way to look at how writeObject is implemented for arrays? I'm not sure where to look. This could be a good approach but, thinking to the future, this makes it hard to read the files without using Java again.

Comment: Yes, I would not use writeObject if it needs to be cross-platform (on the other hand, it is almost certainly just a header and then the sequence of integers). Let me know if you find the implementation for writeObject for primitive arrays (in JDK or Android).

Comment: Actually, using readObject might be a really bad idea. If I have 1Mb of binary data saved as an object, readObject is going create a 1Mb of garbage for the GC to deal with because I don't need two int[]s in memory.

Comment: I've got my bitmap and my int[]. I write the int[] to disk. I then do readObject to get the values back, which creates another int[]. I now have 2 int[]s in memory and I only need one so one becomes garbage.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can make use of the buffer stream concept, just convert partial of your int[] to byte[] and write, and then do the next batch. Try to test and determine a buffer size that is not too demanding on memory but efficient enough, I think a few KBs would be good enough.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way would be to create an NDK lib that writes it out using C functions, then just pass the Int Array using JNI to the C routine.

-niko